# Изменение стилей фрейма из фрейма

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Могу ли я как-то изменить видимость фрейма из самого фрейма? В одном из подключаемых во фрейме скриптов добавляю

```
    window.parent.getElementById("myframe").style.display = "block";
```

, но этот вариант возвращает ошибку `window.parent.getElementById is not a function`.

Сам фрейм в режиме `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"`.

Что можно предпринять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.parent.document.getElementById(...)
```